# THREE JS - Canvas as texture on a sphere

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been trying to stretch a canvas as a texture on a sphere unsuccessfully. 
I have two spheres, one with multiple textures that work fine. The second one 'cloud' with just a canvas. 'cloud' appears as a dark sphere. 
The code goes something like this:

```
<script>

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-60, 30, 60);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor('#00061a', 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMapEnabled =true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// We put all our earth objects into a bigger object, so then can be manipulated as one in the scene.
var group = new THREE.Object3D();
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

var sphereEarth = new THREE.SphereGeometry(20, 120, 120);
var sphereCloud = new THREE.SphereGeometry(20, 120, 120);


var loadmap = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager).load('mapLR.jpg');
var loadbump = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager).load('mapbump.jpg');
var loadspecu = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager).load('mapspecular.jpg');
var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
    {map: loadmap, 
     color: 0xaaaaaa,
     ambient: 0xaaaaaa, 
     specular: 0x333333, 
     shininess: 10});
mat.bumpMap = loadbump;
mat.bumpScale = 0.5;
mat.specularMap = loadspecu;
mat.specular = new THREE.Color('grey');
var earth = new THREE.Mesh(sphereEarth, mat);



var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'mapSmall.jpg';
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = imageObj.width;
canvas.height = imageObj.height;
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);


var cloudTexture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);


var matCl = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x99CCFF});
matCl.map = cloudTexture;

var cloud = new THREE.Mesh(sphereCloud, matCl);



earth.position.set(0, 0, 0);
cloud.position.set(60, 0, 0);
earth.castShadow = true;
cloud.castShadow = true;


group.add(earth);
group.add(cloud);
scene.add(group);


var axesp = new THREE.AxisHelper(90);
var axesn = new THREE.AxisHelper(-90);

scene.add(axesp);
scene.add(axesn);


var spotlight = new THREE.PointLight('#ffffff');
spotlight.power = 12;
spotlight.decay = -1;
spotlight.position.set(-80, 40, 40);
scene.add(spotlight);
spotlight.castShadow =true;



var step = 0;

function renderScene() {        
step += 2 * Math.PI/3600;
requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
earth.rotation.y = (step);

cloud.rotation.y = (step);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}



renderScene();





</script>
```

I have tried everything. Since I have a requestAnimationFrame, I think I should not need Texture loading asynchronicities adjustments.
Thanks in advance for any comments. Cheers

Comment: You have to wait until the image has loaded before you can draw it onto the canvas. Use the image onload event find out when the image has loaded or use the Three texture loader to load the image and assign it to the cloud object.

Comment: Thanks Blindman. I did the following: 1) Moved HTML code to outside the main JS code (created a function init() for the main JS. 2) added cloudTexture.needsUpdate = true; to the render loop, which gets run 60/s due to the animation statement in the loop.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also added: imageObj.onload = function(){
  What I don't understand is, why do I need both? The unload statement AND the texture.needsUpdate = true in the render loop?? Any ideas ? Cheers

Comment: I don`t know three at all. I assume that `needsUpdate` just means the texture is initialised with null `gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, type, null);` and internally when you provide a new map referance the texture data is set then. But that is a guess. You need the onload, and as you are applying a material pre load it (three) needs to know it's empty. You could just not apply a material and then apply it when loaded (if three allows that)

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand what you are saying  :)     Cheers